# REST framework basename missing in reversing action url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls, django-url-reverse

I have this *viewset* with a custom action added

```
@permission_classes([IsStaffUser])
class MacroViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Macro.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MacroSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'head', 'delete']

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True, url_name='add-student')
    def add_student(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

Registered in **urls.py** as

```
# application namespace
app_name = 'appname'

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')
router.register(r'students', StudentViewSet)
router.register(r'macro', MacroViewSet, basename='macro')

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Now, I'm trying to test my custom action. Of course I need its url. Following the [drf guide](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset), I've kwnow of the existence of `reverse_action` method. In my test case, I use that method as following

```
self.url = MacroViewSet().reverse_action('add-student', args=['1'])
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error

```
>       self.url = MacroViewSet().reverse_action('add-student', args=['1'])
E       AttributeError: 'MacroViewSet' object has no attribute 'basename'
```

Comment: when you try to access directly it works? .. what is the result of `MacroViewSet().add_student.url_name`?

Comment: @cabesuon `MacroViewSet().add_student.url_name` --> `add-student`

Comment: OK, can access directly to the endpoint?

Comment: @cabesuon not sure what you asked. I think the endpoint is ok, because `reverse('errepiuapp:macro-add-student', {'1'})`  works fine. On the contrary, no way **reverse_action** works

Comment: I was just checking that the endpoint was working, and to know the full path .. BTW, it's weird, `reverse_action` is just a wrapper of `reverse` ... One more question, if you try `reverse_action` with `user` and `student` it works?

Comment: @cabesuon `UserViewSet().reverse_action('list')` gives the exactly same error: no attribute **basename**, although I configure it in the router. I check with the debugger and when I call the api's view with a client, the basename attribute is set properly. This led me to a thought: maybe I need to call `as_view()` on my ViewSets in order to set *basename* and *request* attribute. But it doesn't work anyway